# Upload APK, google store - different package name

Tags: android, google-play, package

I am receiving this error whenever I try to upload my project to google play. However, I recently did a refactor - rename on my project package - "com.mike.myapplication1_0". I cleaned and rebuilt the file but I am still getting this error. I also updated the Manifest file as well...

[image]

Here is my manifest -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.solomichael.myappppppp" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.solomichael.myappppppp.MyAndroidAppActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.solomichael.myappppppp.probability_act"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_probability_act"
        android:parentActivityName="com.solomichael.myappppppp.MyAndroidAppActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.michael.myandroidappactivity.MyAndroidAppActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.solomichael.myappppppp.showOldCards"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_show_old_cards"
        android:parentActivityName="com.solomichael.myappppppp.MyAndroidAppActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.michael.myandroidappactivity.MyAndroidAppActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

The package name should be unique (across google play store!) so it seems that someone else already used : `com.example` or `com.mike.myapplication1_0` you'll have to choose another name!

**Comment:**
If you already have an app in the app-store and you change the package name and re-upload the apk - you lose all your current users (their app won't get updated!)

Answer (score 0):

In the `<meta-data>` elements of two of your `Activities` you have attributes starting as follows...

```
android:value="com.example.
```

I'm not entirely sure why you have `<meta-data>` elements for those `Activities` but you either need to change the values to reflect your package name or simply delete the `<meta-data>` elements completely unless they're absolutely necessary.